# Silverlight mediaelement buffering

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement, buffering

I wish to play received voice data from network in real-time mode over mediaElement control panel. 
For this purpose it is needed that the control should not buffer.

The MSDN only writes that the default value is 5mp but I try to set it to „0” or under „1” second but it is still buffering data according to 1 second .

Has anybody experienced this problem? Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Have you found a solution?